# TypeError when creating new array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, exception, actionscript, flash-builder

The following line of code sometimes throws an exception:

```
var stopScheduleItems:Array = [];
```

The exception being thrown:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
```

I cannot understand why this could happen when creating a new array.  Could anyone provide some insight.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line can't be throwing this error.

It's more likely that you are trying to access a method of the `stopScheduleItems` object before it's defined. For example something like this:

```
stopScheduleItems.pop();
var stopScheduleItems:Array = [];
```

Comment: Strange.. If you're debugging in Flash Builder make sure you haven't removed a line while debugging, because this often results in incorrect debugging lines shown (so when you see debugger standing at for example line 7, it is actually standing at 7 - deletedLineCount). I can't think of any other thing that could have caused this error.

Comment: You were right.  Another line was actually throwing the error.  Thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you out.